# Add multiple recipient while sending mail throws error - python

Tags: python, email, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a code that should send mail to multiple recipient , but it throws me error when i use multiple recipients.

The error am getting -

**{'error': {'code': 'RequestBodyRead', 'message': "The property 'Email Address' does not exist on type 'microsoft.graph.recipient'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type."}**}

```
def send_email(token, subject, recipients=None, body= None, content_type='HTML', attachments=None):
    try:
        print("inside send mail")
        userId = str(EmailID)
        graph_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/sendMail'
        # Verify that required arguments have been passed.
        if not all([token, subject, recipients]):
            raise ValueError('sendmail(): required arguments missing')
        # Create recipients list in required format.

        recipient_list = [{'Email Address': {'Address': address}} for address in recipients]
        print(recipient_list)
        # Create list of attachments in required format.
        attached_files = []
        if attachments:
            for filename in attachments:
                b64_content = base64.b64encode(open(filename, 'rb').read())
                mine_type = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
                mime_type = mime_type or ''
                attached_files.append(
                    {'@odata. type': '#microsoft. graph. fi LeAttachment',
                     'ContentBytes': b64_content.decode('utf-8'),
                     'ContentType': mime_type,
                     'Name': filename})

        email_msg = {'Message': {'Subject': subject,
                                 'Body': {'ContentType': content_type, 'Content': body},
                                 'ToRecipients': recipient_list,
                                 'Attachments': attached_files},
                     'SaveToSentItems': 'true'}

        res = requests.post(
            graph_url,
            headers={
                'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data=json.dumps(email_msg))
        print(res.json())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

So when printing recipient_list am getting
[{'Email Address': {'Address': 'Heer@company.com'}}, {'Email Address': {'Address': 'harry @company.com'}}]

Can anyone please help me solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the property inside `toRecipients` is `emailAddress` not `Email Address`.

Simply remove the space.

```
recipient_list = [{'emailAddress': {'Address': address}} for address in recipients]
```

Also in attachments you have some spaces: `'@odata. type': '#microsoft. graph. fi LeAttachment'`.

Remove those spaces

```
attached_files.append(
                {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment',
                 'ContentBytes': b64_content.decode('utf-8'),
                 'ContentType': mime_type,
                 'Name': filename})
```

There is no reason to call `res.json()` because this request doesn't return any response body.

[User sendMail response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response)

Comment: i edited it , and now am getting Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error

Comment: @askquestions Could you share what is returned by json.dumps(email_msg)? There is probably another issue with the json. Which line in your code throws this exception? Maybe res.json()?

Comment: {"Message": {"Subject": "--Hi",
  "Body": {"ContentType": "HTML", "Content": "Hello"}, "ToRecipients": [{"emailAddress": {"Address": "A@company.com"}}, {"emailAddress": {"Address": "b@company.com"}}], "Attachments": []}, "SaveToSentItems": "true"}

Comment: @askquestions The json looks correct. Why do you call res.json()? POST request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/sendMail doesn't return any data only status code. It does not return anything in the response body.

Comment: when i print res it is showing me response 202

Comment: @askquestions Then no need to call res.json() if this request doesn't return any response body

Comment: i removed it and print(res) - gave me response 202

Comment: @askquestions 202 means that the request was successful.

Comment: oops sorry i was checking in wrongfolder inside outlook